# How to mock Spring's @Retryable attributes such as maxAttemps and delay in SpringBootTest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito, spring-retry

I have a method which I'm trying to test

```
@Retryable(value = {SocketTimeoutException.class},
             backoff = @Backoff(delay = 10000),
             maxAttempts = 4)
public String getNewString(String oldString) throws IOException{
   ...
}
```

I have created it's test case like so:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class TestStrings {
  @Test(expected = SocketTimeoutException.class)
  public void testGetNewString() throws IOException {
     ...
  }
```

Everything works great, the test case runs 4 times with a delay of 10sec. But I want to change the attributes of @Retryable, namely maxAttempts from 4 to 2 and delay from 10s to 0.5s for this specific test case.
I want to do this so that when running the test cases it should not wait for a long time and the test case should end quickly meanwhile also testing the retry functionality.

Comment: You cannot, unless you make them configurable and run with a specific test configuration.

Comment: Use the `...expression` variants with property placeholders.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
@Retryable(maxAttemptsExpression = "${max.attempts:4}", 
        backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "${delay:10000}"))
```

and set the properties in your test case.

Comment: I almost forgot I could do this. Was working along the lines of mocking RetryProperties with the specific properties.
Thanks!

Comment: Oof, wish I would have seen this earlier.  Thx.